# how to create a Json array of strings in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to create an array like this `["stringone","stringtwo"]` and pass it to the webserver. When I tried doing making it with a string array like `String[]={"stringone","stringtwo"]` it passed in something weird `{"userids":"[Ljava.lang.String;@406fe4b8"}` how should I be constructing my JSON array if not by using string arrays?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to create `JSONArray` from `List` or array, you can use constructor, which takes `Collection`:

```
String[] data = {"stringone", "stringtwo"};
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(data));
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create a [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) object and use the put method(s) to add any Strings you want.  To output the result, just use the toString() method.